# Find next (keyboard shortcut) in the Sources tab of Google Chrome Developer tools

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

*Developer Tools -> Sources[tab] -> <kbd>Ctl-F</kbd>*

Is there a keyboard shortcut to *Find Next* , or go to the next match in a search that found several matches?  (In windows world this is usually F3.)

Ironically, in regular searching of a webpage in Chrome, <kbd>F3</kbd> goes to next match.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Press <kbd>Return</kbd> on your keyboard.

Comment: Not required, but if you can point me to documentation [where you found that], I may gain more wisdom on potential other devtools shortcuts .  Thanks !

Comment: It was just something I naturally knew or tried in the past. Many text editors and IDEs work that way. See [Shortcuts](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/iterate/inspect-styles/shortcuts) for a list of useful DevTool shortcuts, but this one is not included there.

Comment: Hitting Return only works when the focus is still on the search input box. It would be good to know how to do a find next when the focus is in the source window

Answer (score 5):

- To find the next match Press `Return` or `Ctrl + g`
- To find the previous match Press `Shift + Return` or `Ctrl + Shift + g`

[Link to Chrome keyboard shortcuts](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179?hl=en#zippy=%2Cgoogle-chrome-feature-shortcuts)